# Docusign API request for processing already processed docusign doc

Tags: docusignapi

We have some documents which has DocuSign Envelope ID on top of documents. So is there any API present which help us to extract the values like 'date of sign', 'who signed it' etc. from the documents.

(Note - These documents are processed by others we have only there documents.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The DocuSign API only allows you to pull data from envelopes you already have access to. In this case, I would recommend reaching out to a party on the envelope to request they provide the Certificate of Completion.